# Selenium entered value in input text box is not visible during run time and hence test failed

Tags: selenium

Selenium entered a value in input text box is not visible during run time and hence test failed

When the test runs as per the test steps the value is entered in the Input text box but when it moves to last text box, the previous text box values are not visible and textbox looks empty. Hence test failed as unable to proceed.

Selenium: 2.53.0
Firefox: 45

Code:

```
getDriver().switchTo().frame(
                getDriver().findElement(
                        By.xpath("//iframe[@src='/bi-sac-config-mgr/SMTP']")));
        if (!waitForObject("psm_nhp_mailsave", m_largeTime * 2)) {
            getLogger().error("Save mail settings unavailable");
        } else {

            waitForObject("psmsacmailserverxpath", m_largeTime * 2);
            setObject("psmsacmailserverxpath",
                    "internal-mail-router.gmail.com");

            waitForObject("psmsacmailportxpath", m_largeTime * 2);
            setObject("psmsacmailportxpath", "25");

            waitForObject("psmsacmaildisplaynamexpath", m_largeTime * 2);
            setObject("psmsacmaildisplaynamexpath", "matstest");

            waitForObject("psmsacmailemailxpath", m_largeTime * 2);
            setObject("psmsacmailemailxpath", "matstest@gmail.com");
```

In the above code, after entering `psmsacmailserverxpath` which is a mandatory text field, the value gets disappeared runtime. Manually it works fine. In automation using Selenium, this issue is seen.

html element:

```
<input id="mail-server-input" class="oj-form-control oj-inputtext oj-inputtext-input oj-component-initnode" data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojInputText',
                                    invalidComponentTracker: tracker,
                                    value:smtpConfig.host,
                                    required: true,
                                        validators: [{type: 'length',
                                            options: {min: 0,
                                                max: 250,
                                                hint:null}}],
                                        displayOptions:{validatorHint: 'none'}}" type="text" placeholder="" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true">
```

Comment: Hi @Arthi Vigneshwari, welcome to StackOverflow, can you share more information about your question, html source and your code of try?

Comment: I have provided the html source and code I tried above. Enter key should be pressed after entering value in textfield?